# Comparing Multiple Values with AND using ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

As part of a larger formula I need to use an AND statement to compare 2 columns. An example is a table like this:

```
| A | B |
|---|---|
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 |
```

The formula I'm trying is pretty simple. Basically just `ARRAYFORMULA(AND(A1:A>2, B1:B>3))`. My expectation is the result would be

```
False
False
True
```

But I just get `False` on a single line. Can you use `AND` in an `ARRAYFORMULA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AND` is not supported in `ARRAYFORMULA`

do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA((A1:A>2)*(B1:B>3))
```